# ffmpeg command for create final video from two different videos and two different audios

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have two videos and two audios

1:-
video 1 - length:- 60 sec  ||   audio 1 -  length:- 15 sec

2:-
video  - length:- 86 sec  ||   audio 2 -  length:- 18 sec

Play video1 and audio1 together, if audio1 is ended then restart that audio till video1 end. this will **final video 1**.

same way,

play video2 and audio2 together, if audio2 is ended then restart that audio till video2 end. this will **final video 2**.

after that **concatenate** those final video 1 and final video 2 and create single video as output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will the videos and audios always have the same attributes (format, width, height, sample rate, channel layout, etc), or will they vary? Fastest way to get answer you can copy and paste is by showing file and ffmpeg info with: `ffmpeg -n -i video1 -i audio1 -i video2 -i audio2`

Comment: Video and audio attributes are vary every time user choose video. this is just an example. I am creating output video from this kind of audio and video. help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because your inputs are arbitrary you need to make them the same before concatenation.

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video1 -stream_loop -1 -i audio1 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -ac 2 -ar 44100 -shortest temp1.mp4
   ffmpeg -i video2 -stream_loop -1 -i audio2 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -ac 2 -ar 44100 -shortest temp2.mp4
   ```
2. Concatenate.

   Make `input.txt`:

   ```
   file 'temp1.mp4'
   file 'temp2.mp4'
   ```

   Run `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
   ```

---

As a "single line command" as requested (but make `input.txt` first):

```
ffmpeg -i video1 -stream_loop -1 -i audio1 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -ac 2 -ar 44100 -shortest temp1.mp4 && ffmpeg -i video2 -stream_loop -1 -i audio2 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -ac 2 -ar 44100 -shortest temp2.mp4 && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. but I need this using single line command. because I want to show the progress of that operation too.  is that any way for doing this with single line command?

Comment: @KashyapRathod See updated answer for "single line command".

Comment: Tank you so much, this is working fine. I got the error ''The system cannot find the file specified.' then is change last line from '&& ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" temp*.mp4) -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4' to '&& ffmpeg -i temp1.mp4 -i temp2.mp4 -filter_complex [0][1]concat=n=2 output.mp4' and done. Thank you so much again.

Comment: @KashyapRathod I guess printf and/or bash doesn't work on Andriod. Your command is slow and will reduce quality because it will unnecessarily re-encode the video. The first two ffmpeg commands in my answer make the videos have the same attributes so they can be concatenated by the third ffmpeg command without needing to be re-encoded. See updated answer.